# Adding more promoted properties after a first one in BizTalk

Tags: properties, xsd, biztalk

I've got a BizTalk solution where I added a schema, and promoted a field

 - this added the default PropertySchema.xsd with the element in

A bit later, added another schema, but when I try and promote a couple of fields, but when I select Show Promotions, I end up mapping the new field to one of the existing fields in the PropertySchema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad ... I should have used the Quick Promote

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add items to the property schema as you would with correlation and then associate the promoted property.